# How to set a timer for a modal dialog to appear at the press of a button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, modal-dialog, settimeout

Hi I have an onclick button. When I press this onclick button, a modal dialog should appear after 5seconds (5000 milliseconds). However after 5 seconds the modal closes and reopends after 5 as if its been looped. Everything looks fine with the code but I don't know where I am going wrong.

What I want:

1) When the onclick is pressed, the modal dialog opens after 5 seconds. The modal shouldn't close unless someone presses the save button.
2) When The "save" button is pressed the modal dialogue closes and is reset.
3) The modal dialogue doesn't reopen itself again. It only opens 5 seconds after the button is clicked.

I hope that is clear.

Any helped would be appreciated

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
setTimeout(toggleModal, 5000)
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
```

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.close-button {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.close-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<button class="trigger">Click here </button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      
        <h1>
          <label><b>Please state your confidence with this decision (0-100%)</b></label>
          <p>
         <input class="bottomaftertrialquestions" type="number" placeholder="Type here" name="conf1d3nce"min="0" max="100" required>
          </p>
          <p></h1>
            <button type="button" class="close-button">SAVE</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

. I am unsure what is wrong with my code to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're causing the loop yourself with this function:

```
function toggleModal() {
    setTimeout(toggleModal, 5000);
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}
```

This defines a function called `toggleModal`, which does two things:

1) schedules `toggleModal` to run in 5 seconds' time
2) toggles the `show-modal` class.

1) is the important thing here: the function schedules itself to run again in 5 seconds, each time it runs - thereby ensuring that, when called once, it will continue to be called every 5 seconds from then onwards.

So don't schedule the same function in the `setTimeout`, instead schedule the effect you want - the toggling of the class. This can be done most simply with an anonymous function:

```
function toggleModal() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }, 5000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, and the page will alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```